# Publish unit test results on GitHub for all matrix build versions

Tags: java, unit-testing, github, github-actions

Currently, I'm trying to understand a (Java JUnit) test failure on a project, which only appears occasionally and on different JVM versions. To speed up examination of the failure, I am trying to get the test reports automatic on GitHub actions with a matrix build, but I did not find a way to do so.

I tried two plugins, action-surefire-report (https://github.com/ScaCap/action-surefire-report) and publish-unit-test-results (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-unit-test-results).

With the `action-surefire-report`, I tried to set the name or other properties:

```
- name: Publish Test Report ${{ matrix.java }}
  if: ${{ always() }}
  uses: scacap/action-surefire-report@v1
  with:
     github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Unfortunately, no try resulted in publishing reports of more than one JVM.

For publish-unit-test-results, which contains an example of publishing python test results by downloading artifacts of the same build, I tried to copy this behavior:

```
  publish-test-results:
    name: "Publish Unit Tests Results"
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: success() || failure()
    steps:
    - name: Download Artifacts
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        path: artifacts
    - name: Publish Unit Test Results
      uses: EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action@v1
      with:
        check_name: Unit Test Results
        files: "target/surefire-reports/*.xml"
```

This fails, apparently since I cannot name the concrete xml-files of the test report.

The example code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/DaGeRe/multiple-version-publish-test-results)

Is it possible to get a test report for each JVM version of my current build? Since this is a pretty standard task to get test results for JUnit runs, I would have assumed that something like this is already implemented somewhere, and I am just not finding the documentation.

Comment: `publish-unit-test-results` errors with *"GitHub token must be provided via action input or environment variable GITHUB_TOKEN"*. So just pass it the input like you already do with the `action-surefire-report` action.

Comment: The latest `v1` version of `publish-unit-test-results` now works without providing a GitHub token, so that should be resolved. Simply re-run your workflow.

Comment: The artifacts are downloaded to `artifacts`, but the `publish-unit-test-results` action is configured to look into `target/...`. This won't work. Try `files: artifacts/target/surefire-reports/*.xml`.

Comment: If you know the only XML files that will be in your published artifacts will be those from the unit tests you can use `**/*.xml` to easily capture tests strewn across multiple modules if your project has more than one.